# Standalone Kotlin Gradle plugin not found when trying to apply to other project

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to make a custom standalone Kotlin plugin for Gradle and am trying to apply that to another project, but am getting a `Plugin with id 'my.id.license-tools' not found` error when trying to apply it to another project.

This is the structure of the plugin's project:

```
license-tools
+--src
   +--main
   |  +--java
   |  |
   |  +--kotlin
   |  |  +--my.id
   |  |     +--LicenseTools.kt
   |  |
   |  +--resources
   |     +--META-INF.gradle-plugins
   |        +--my.id.license-tools.properties
   +--test
   +--build.gradle
```

This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

group 'my.id'
version '0.1'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven'


sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compile gradleApi()
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Then we have the Plugin class `LicenseTools.kt`, which I've held very simple to make sure the error didn't come from there:

```
package my.id

import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

open class LicenseTools: Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project?) {
        println("License-Tools plugin has been applied")
    }
}
```

And lastly `my.id.license-tools.properties`:

```
implementation-class=my.id.LicenseToolsKt
```

I've also tried

```
implementation-class=my.id.LicenseTools
```

After building everything with `./gradlew clean build` I've run `./gradlew install` to install the whole thing to the local Maven repository, which it did successfully.

Then I went ahead and added the following to my other project's buildscript block:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "my.id:license-tools:0.1"
}
```

And after that added

```
apply plugin: 'my.id.license-tools'
```

After trying out many different things, like changing to the new plugins block or making sure the artifacts get correctly installed to the local maven repository I can't find the root of the problem, since according to the many guides I've read through, this should be the correct way to go about making a standalone plugin.

Answer (score 0):

you probably figured by now, but your `my.id.license-tools.properties` should be named `my.id.properties`

the content should then be `implementation-class=my.id.LicenseTools`

then the classpath should be named
`classpath "my.id:license-tools:0.1"` -> `classpath "my.id:LicenseTools:0.1"`

and
`apply plugin: 'my.id.license-tools'` -> `apply plugin: 'my.id.LicenseTools'`

so that it always is:

- package: `my.id`
- name: `LicenseTools`

I haven't actually tested all of that, though.